# Why "Delete your root access keys" security status is shown as ticked in AWS IAM console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have no understanding on why this status is shown as checked and I don't recall anything as like I deleted any keys.
Can someone let me know why this shows as checked by default ? I haven't created any keys yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't created any keys, that would be sort of the same as them being deleted.

AWS strongly recommends that you don't use root account keys, in fact they strongly recommend not using the root account, but instead creating an IAM user for yourself.